# Different news types in Sharepoint modern

Tags: sharepoint

I am buiding a landing page in Sharepoint 2019. I am using the 'News' component and I have succesfully created news that are shown in that component.

Now I want to create another webpart in the landing page displaying 'Announcements' with the same list design as the 'News'. But when I insert the 'News' component again it shows the same news as in the first component and I have no possibilities of selecting a different source for that component.

I can't use the classic 'Announcements' app as it can be referenced from the modern list.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the WebPart Properties, you can change the source, Add PageLinks and if necessary, you can filter the content.